# Modifying a copied list is altering the original

Tags: list, dart, flutter

I have two screens that I'm passing a list from one to the other. The list type is a custom object that has another list inside of it. On the second screen, a random item is removed from the sublist until there are no more, at which point the item containing the empty list is also removed. This happens until there are no more items in the top level list. The problem is, when the list is modified, the item stay gone. Entering the second screen will pass along an empty list.

This is how I'm making the list copy that is being passed forward:

```
_pushWordLists(List<WordList>.from(_selections.values));

_pushWordLists(List<WordList> wordLists) {
  Navigator.of(context).push(
    MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => CardWidget(wordLists)
    )
  );
}
```

And this is how I'm modifying the list:

```
_loadNewWord() {
    if (wordLists.length > 0) {
        wordLists.shuffle();

        final wordList = wordLists.first;

        if (wordList.words.length > 0) {
            wordList.words.shuffle();
            var words = List<String>.from(wordList.words);

            final word = words.first;
            words.remove(word);

            wordList.words = words;

            setState(() {
                _multiplier = wordList.multiplier;
                _word = word;
            });
        } else {
            wordLists.remove(wordList);

            _loadNewWord();
        }
    } else {
        _done();
    }
}
```

I was told that making a copy would allow me to modify it's length and also keep the original list intact. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just calling `.toList()` on a `List` should return a copy.

Comment: Just changed to that in both places and it still didn't work.

Comment: Then the problem is probably unrelated to creating copies of the list.

Comment: Any thoughts on what it could be from?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you operate original instances of `WordList`, instead of copies.

In the first line of first sample:

```
List<WordList>.from(_selections.values)
```

will create a *new list* with *same instances* of `WordList`, as `_selection`. The list object itself is new, but it contains same WordLists as `_selection`.

In the second sample

```
    final wordList = wordLists.first;
```

takes an instance of `WordList` from passed list (remember, this instance is also included in original `_selection`) and

```
        wordList.words = words;
```

updates it.

Solution: line `List<WordList>.from(_selections.values)` should be replaces with something to actually create a new list of actual clones of WordLists in `_selection`. Importing `dart:convert` and using `JSON.decode(JSON.encode(object))` will **not** work in Flutter. So, you, most likely, have to come with own `cloneFrom(WordList source)` method.

Comment: I had a similar problem, List.of List.from List.unmodifiable, convert to a map and then back to list, none of them worked. 
Only encoding and decoding to/from JSON did the trick. thanks!